# unable to install MSI package using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, psexec

I have this powershell Script and it's not running the bat file.

```
$computerlist = Get-Content C:\PSTools\computers.txt

foreach($computer in $computerlist)
{
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
        & C:\pstools\psexec.exe \\$computer -h -u "DOMAIN\admin.name" -p "p@s$w0rd" C:\install\install.bat
    }
}
```

My original script was

```
$computerlist = Get-Content C:\PSTools\computers.txt

foreach($computer in $computerlist)
{
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
        & C:\pstools\psexec.exe \\$computer -h -u "DOMAIN\admin.name" -p "p@s$w0rd" cmd /c "msiexec /i "C:\Update\install_flash_player_16_active_x.msi" /quiet /norestart"
    }
}
```

The error message I am seeing says

```
 PsExec could not start C:\install\install.bat on WORKSTATION1:
```

If I run the same command in command prompt, it works without any problem. So I know it's something that I am doing wrong with PowerShell

Comment: Try `-p 'p@s$w0rd'` i.e. with single quotes. `$` is used to denote a variable in powershell so your password might be getting converted to `p@s` (And also don't post passwords...)

Comment: my real password doesn't contain the $ but it's good to know. the password displayed is totally fake and so is the account name.

Comment: @arco444 I tried your suggestion and it still fails